# fatal: No configured push destination

Tags: git, github

```
$ git commit -am "WP changes"
[master (root-commit) 747a474] WP changes     
 38 files changed, 4260 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .eslintrc
 create mode 100644 .stylelintrc.json
 create mode 100644 404.php
 create mode 100644 LICENSE
 create mode 100644 README.md
 create mode 100644 archive.php
 create mode 160000 assets
 create mode 100644 bin/bundle.js
 create mode 100644 comments.php
 create mode 100644 composer.json
 create mode 100644 footer.php
 create mode 100644 functions.php
 create mode 100644 header.php
 create mode 100644 inc/custom-header.php     
 create mode 100644 inc/customizer.php        
 create mode 100644 inc/jetpack.php
 create mode 100644 inc/template-functions.php
 create mode 100644 inc/template-tags.php     
 create mode 100644 index.php
 create mode 100644 js/customizer.js
 create mode 100644 js/navigation.js
 create mode 100644 js/skip-link-focus-fix.js 
 create mode 100644 languages/modelist.pot
 create mode 100644 languages/readme.txt
 create mode 100644 package.json
 create mode 100644 page.php
 create mode 100644 phpcs.xml.dist
 create mode 100644 readme.txt
 create mode 100644 screenshot.png
 create mode 100644 search.php
 create mode 100644 sidebar.php
 create mode 100644 single.php
 create mode 100644 style-rtl.css
 create mode 100644 style.css
 create mode 100644 template-parts/content-none.php
 create mode 100644 template-parts/content-page.php
 create mode 100644 template-parts/content-search.php
 create mode 100644 template-parts/content.php
$ git push
fatal: No configured push destination.
Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository using

    git remote add <name> <url>

and then push using the remote name

    git push <name>
```

Comment: вернул редакцию к первой ошибке: именно про неё вам дан ответ. вторая ошибка: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh . будут трудности — задавайте **новый** вопрос вместо изменения того, на который уже дан ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перевожу что хочет от тебя git: у тебя не задано куда пушить. На вопрос "А что делать?" тоже есть ответы у тебя же:

```
git remote add <name, обычно это origin> <url репозитория>
git push --set-upstream <name, который указал выше> <branch, имя текущей ветки>
```

Далее можно будет пушить просто с помощью `git push`

Comment: Спасибо, но возникла ошибка с ключем
$ git push --set-upstream WP master
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.      

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Моя догадка: ты не добавил свой публичный ключ в гитхаб.